# Python using graphics.py

Tags: python, graphics, geometry

How do you trace on the graphics window where the user clicks?

I have to create a circle at the point they clicked and am not sure where to begin.

I tried;

```
win.getMouse()
center = Point(win.getMouse(),win.getMouse())
circ = Circle(center, 30)
circ.draw(win)
```

but obviously that doesn't work

Comment: Which GUI library do you use? I'd suggest looking up getMouse() definition and what it returns - it'd be strange to expect a function that returns x on the first call and y on the second. I'd rather expect something like this:
`x,y,smthelse,smthelse = win.getMouse()` then `center = Point(x,y)`
and further as you code goes.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial code:

```
win.getMouse()
center = Point(win.getMouse(),win.getMouse())
circ = Circle(center, 30)
circ.draw(win)
```

can be edited to work and condensed to:

```
Circle(win.getMouse(), 30).draw(win)
```

That assumes win is an instance of the GraphWin class and has already been declared. win.getMouse returns a Point object, so there is no need to change a point into coordinate pairs just to change it back into a point...